# Why is phenyl shift preferred over methyl shift in cumene hydroperoxide reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In the cumene process, which converts cumene to phenol and acetone, there is a step where cumene hydroperoxide undergoes acid-catalyzed rearrangement:

[image: A reaction scheme showing the rearrangement of cumene hydroperoxide in acid]

(Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumene_process))

Why does the phenyl shift happen preferentially? The methyl group is smaller and should have a higher migratory aptitude.

Answer (score 15):

Despite the mechanism shown in your question, which is commonly used to depict a phenyl shift, phenyl shifts occur by a slightly different mechanism.

[image: A scheme showing the mechanism of cumene hydroperoxide rearrangement through formation of a resonance-stabilized spriobicyclic cation]

Phenyl shifts do not usually happen by the normal 1,2-sigmatropic "hop". Instead, the phenyl group shifts by more of a "walk". It's not really a sigmatropic rearrangement. First, one of the $\pi$-bonds in the phenyl group can attack the electrophilic center. This leads to formation of a spirobicyclic intermediate where the cation is delocalized throughout the rest of the ring. Then, the three-member ring breaks open at the expense of a carbon-carbon bond to rearomatize the phenyl ring and form the new resonance stabilized cation.

Comment: That's pretty neat. Is this mode assumed based on kinetics from ring substitution?

Comment: I wonder if there is a name for the intermediate carbocation. I recall the carbon analogue is called a [phenonium ion](https://goldbook.iupac.org/P04541.html) and can arise via [similar chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbouring_group_participation#NGP_by_an_aromatic_ring), however the IUPAC definition strictly disqualifies this one with an oxygen in it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! If I may ask, could you please tell how do _we_ know the phenyl shift occurs by a "walk" and not a "hop"? (nice analogy btw!) Do we have experimental evidences, or some other proof? Many thanks!